# Optimizing MySQL-query

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have the following MySQL query

```
SELECT e.id, IF(c.id = 1, g.url, e.url) AS url, IF(s.id = 4, c.short, s.name) AS sub, e.title, b.name AS category
FROM g, c, e, b, s
WHERE e.category = b.id
AND e.subcategory = s.id
AND g.c = c.id
AND (g.g = e.id OR s.id != 4)
AND e.`release` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
GROUP BY e.id
ORDER BY e.`release` DESC
LIMIT 15
```

This took about 2.5 seconds. But if I remove the GROUP BY, it takes about 1.8 seconds. If I remove ORDER BY, it takes 2.3 seconds. BUT if I remove GROUP BY and ORDER BY, it tooks about 0.005 seconds (but then there is many duplicate rows).

What should I do to get same results with faster time?

Here is the explain of the query, if it helps.

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref  rows   Extra
1   SIMPLE  c   ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    26  Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  g   ref console console 4   int41988_leveli.consoles.id 60  
1   SIMPLE  e   ALL PRIMARY,id  NULL    NULL    NULL    208 Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE  b   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   e.cat   1   
1   SIMPLE  s   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   e.subcategory   1
```

EDIT:

Here are the indexes that already exist.

```
c.id PRIMARY KEY
b.id PRIMARY KEY
e.id PRIMARY KEY
s.id PRIMARY KEY
g.id PRIMARY KEY
g.url AND g.console UNIQUE INDEX
```

Comment: That query looks pretty optimal, horrible table/column names though.  Is e.release indexed?

Comment: Can you show us the create table statements for these? In particular, which indexes already exist?

Comment: I added the indexes to the question

Answer (score 1):

Try using single index on both fields: e.id and e.release. Or one index per each field: e.id and e.resourse, but I doubt it helps.

Answer (score 0):

How long does it take when you use `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` clause?

Answer (score 0):

Try `join`ing the tables one by one instead of the 5 of them all together and then restricting it with `where`. Start with most restricting `join`s, that is joining tables that produce fewer rows first.